# Python 2 dis.dis() can not parse string contains `for` loop syntax

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.4

With Python 3, [dis.dis()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis) work well with parsing string contain `for` loop syntax:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('for _ in range(10): pass')
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 23)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 22)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (_)
             19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   22 POP_BLOCK
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

In Python 2, it produced `string index out of range` error:

```
In [30]: dis.dis('for _ in range(10): pass')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-b7c7c1c77064> in <module>()
----> 1 dis.dis('for _ in range(10): pass')

/usr/lib/python2.7/dis.pyc in dis(x)
     43         disassemble(x)
     44     elif isinstance(x, str):
---> 45         disassemble_string(x)
     46     else:
     47         raise TypeError, \

/usr/lib/python2.7/dis.pyc in disassemble_string(code, lasti, varnames, names, constants)
    110 def disassemble_string(code, lasti=-1, varnames=None, names=None,
    111                        constants=None):
--> 112     labels = findlabels(code)
    113     n = len(code)
    114     i = 0

/usr/lib/python2.7/dis.pyc in findlabels(code)
    164         i = i+1
    165         if op >= HAVE_ARGUMENT:
--> 166             oparg = ord(code[i]) + ord(code[i+1])*256
    167             i = i+2
    168             label = -1

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Even wrapping `for` loop in a function for regular syntax didn't help:

```
def test():
    for _ in range(10):
        pass

dis.dis('test')
<The same error>
```

Is this a bug or desired behavior documented else where?

**Software Version**

```
$ python2 -V
Python 2.7.9

$ python3 -V
Python 3.4.2

$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 2's `dis.dis` does not take a string containing Python code as an argument, it takes a string containing *bytecode* or a function.

Your best bet is something like this:

```
>>> def test():
...     for _ in range(10):
...         pass
...
>>>
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 23)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 22)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (_)

  3          19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   22 POP_BLOCK
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Another option is to call `compile` on the sting (with a made up filename like `"<string>"` and `"exec"` as the other params) and pass the code object you get back to `dis.dis`.

Comment: Well, I messed up my test, I was in Python 3 shell and think I was in Python 2 shell. I read `dis.dis` docstring from that.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Python 2 dis.dis](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/dis.html#dis.dis) documentation, the parameters only allow bytecode, string doesn't.

And [Python 3 dis.dis()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#dis.dis) now accept string as argument.

I think you forgot read documentation before do this.